# Laravel 5.8 Manual user approval?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I am new to laravel and before asking this question. I have read various other topics regarding this question sadly none of them helped me.

I have laravel 5.8 and use auth which I installed with:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Now I read that I either need to make a middleware or edit the logincontroller. But what I want is the user to be redirected to a custom page that I already made saying they need to wait to be approved.

Could someone point me in the right direction and tell me which files I need to edit to achieve this?

I have already added a `BIT` column in the database table called `is_approved` which is auto set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In your

> App/Htpp/Controllers/Auth

you'll find all the logic of authentication and registration of the user. Inside the controllers, you'll see this:

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after verification.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Last line is what you're looking for, it's pointing the view/route where your user will be redirected after the respective action.

Also, all your generated views when you run the make:auth command will be in

> resources/views/auth

if you feel the need to modify them.

Answer (score 1):

Go here. HomeController. Under return view('home'); change it to

```
if (Auth::user()->is_approved === "1"){
  return view('home');
} else {
  return view('welcome');
}
```

Where 'welcome' you can change to your custom page and '1' assumes the user has been approved. Remember to add use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; to the top of that controller. I had that problem and came to read your post. Thought to drop what I did. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to build a user approval system. A common way is store an `active` state on the users table as a boolean MySQL column. Then check that column if a user tries to login. As for registration you need to write to the users table with an `active` state of 0 or false. It would be also great to trigger a notification to you the admin that "hey, you need to go approve a new user". It could be handled through Laravel Nova dashboard where ideally you only need to click a button.

It's not built into the Laravel framework but definitely seems like a good use case!